# Javascript bookmarklet...I think browser is replacing characters

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, bookmarklet

I have this lovely javascript bookmarklet...

```
javascript:var nam="blablabla&amp;name"; var els=document.getElementsByName(nam); if(els.length == 0) alert(nam); else els[0].click();
```

when I put that in I get this result:

blablabla)name

so basically I think the browser (or something) is automatically replacing the & with the ).  I need it to not do that.  I want whatever is between the "" after nam= to be sent exactly as is.  How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `" "` while doing a bookmarklet, because those will close the attribute try to use `' '` instead

Comment: Thanks.  That did exactly what I asked!  Unfortunately its still not working as I hoped it would after fixing that problem. lol  Back to the drawing board!  Thanks again!

Comment: What are you trying to do? I might give a help =)

Comment: Basically I need to have the javascript click a link based on the name.  Its just odd because if I have the bookmarklet pop up a input box and paste the link in there and hit ok (to get the nam= variable) it works fine.  But if I just do nam='link' it fails. :-(

Comment: Here's a link about it where I asked before and could not come up with a soloution:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3832784/bookmarklet-not-working-as-it-should-i-think

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is not the javascript-variable, it's the name-attribute. If you have there an entity it will be translated to the corresponding character. So if you really have a name like:

```
<a name="blablabla&amp;name">
```

you'll have to set the variable to

```
var nam='blablabla&name';
```

Comment: This is an example of an actual name element that I'm looking for: 
action[http://apps.facebook.com/onthefarm/sendcredits.php?feature=holidaytree2010&receiverId=100001413889651&ts=1294102505&key=051ebdaf34c701b50378d263a4142572%24%24ccF%28NVST06rHQ%28VULNW8T_c%21cLP%2CyM%21qSxQoVmidkpzcvCTAL21gvJmqoOUy%29s-voksj]

That's copied right from the "inspect element" in firefox.  If that helps.